# Simple REST service with Jersey running on Servlet 3.0 / Tomcat 7.0 not running but http status 500

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey

I am testing a very simple REST server with Jersey and Servlet 3.0 implementation on Tomcat 7.0. I have programmed a simple PoJo:

```
package toplevel;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("/pojo")
public class PoJo {

    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain") 
    public String hello() {

        return "Hello, World"; 
    }
}
```

I have put the following in the WEB-INF/web.xml file (running on Servlet 3.0):

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<display-name>RestTest</display-name>    

  <servlet> 
    <servlet-name>toplevel.PoJo</servlet-name>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>toplevel.PoJo</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/pojo</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

When I deploy, I get a HTTP Status 500 response. This seems to me that the webserver is recognizing that something should be served from /pojo, but that the corresponding class PoJo is not found. The jersey specific jars (version 1.17) are in the WEB-INF/lib dir:

```
activation-1.1.1.jar   jersey-client-1.17.jar  junit-4.9.jar
asm-3.3.1.jar          jersey-core-1.17.jar    persistence-api-1.0.2.jar
jaxb-api-2.2.4.jar     jersey-server-1.17.jar  stax-api-1.0-2.jar
jaxb-impl-2.2.4-1.jar  jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar
```

Does anyone recognize this ?

Comment: Surely the 500 comes with some details? (Just in case: don't test in IE, that browser might hide useful messages from you.)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yeah...type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.NullPointerException
 sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
 java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1629)
 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:461)

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell Jersey where to find your REST resource. Your web.xml should look something like this:

```xml
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Service</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>toplevel</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Service</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks for you quick response, but I believe this is not correct since I work with Servlet 3.0 and Jersey 1.17. See the **Example 2.11**. Deployment of a JAX-RS application using web.xml with Servlet 3.0 on http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d4e188

Comment: Yes - but in the example the resource extends `Application`. Your resource does not.

Comment: Hmmm....the PoJo does not need to extend Application. The file you mean is used for deploying without `web.xml`....

Comment: You'll need a `web.xml`. If you don't define a class that extends `Application` you can use the `web.xml` example I provided. See http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html

Comment: I did provide a web.xml, see above in the post. But I am running on Servlet 3.0, and hence have no need to include a `<servlet-class/>` property.

Comment: Right - in that case have you specified your `ApplicationPath` (section 2.9 of the example)?

Comment: Nope, I want to deploy using the `web.xml` method, and not code it into the app.

Comment: After reading the Jersey user guide a bit again, I wonder what they mean with: "JAX-RS 1.1 specifies that a fully qualified name of the class that implements **Application** may be declared in the  <servlet-name> element of the JAX-RS application's web.xml." I am puzzled now, does this mean that this implemenation of Rest requires `PoJo` to `implement Application` ?

Comment: Well, seems `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` is not an interface...so...forgot my previous remark.

Answer (score 0):

Adding jersey-servlet:1.17.jar took care of that problem for me.